# I wish to extract several nodes in an XML document based on their content using ksh Script

Tags: ksh, xml

pre requisite:Should be done using ksh script commands

I have the following document, and need to extract all the `<Sw:RMARecrd>`s whose `<Doc:Crspdt>` children contain `BSDTUS30` or `MITMUS30`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Sw:RMAFile xmlns:Sw="urn:swift:snl:ns.Sw" xmlns:Doc="urn:swift:snl:ns.Doc" xmlns:SwSec="urn:swift:snl:ns.SwSec">

<Sw:RMAFileHdr>
<Sw:Bic8Lst>
<Doc:Bic8>BSDTGB20</Doc:Bic8>
<Doc:Bic8>BSDTUS30</Doc:Bic8>
Doc:Bic8>BWTRUS30</Doc:Bic8>
<Doc:Bic8>MELNJPJ0</Doc:Bic8>
<Doc:Bic8>NEIMGB20</Doc:Bic8>
<Doc:Bic8>ZYHJGB20</Doc:Bic8>
<Doc:Bic8>ZYIYUS30</Doc:Bic8>
<Doc:Bic8>ZYJDGB20</Doc:Bic8>
</Sw:Bic8Lst>

<Sw:SvcLst>
<Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
</Sw:SvcLst>

<Sw:FileMaintncSts>Partial</Sw:FileMaintncSts>
<Sw:FileDesc/><Sw:CrDtTm>2016-08-01T10:17:02Z</Sw:CrDtTm>
<Sw:TltRecrd>254</Sw:TltRecrd>
<Sw:LAU><Sw:LAUVal>RRgL2lsocXDswCHxgnf4ww==</Sw:LAUVal></Sw:LAU>

</Sw:RMAFileHdr>

<Sw:RMARecrd>
<Sw:Tp>Received</Sw:Tp>
<Sw:RMASts>Rejected</Sw:RMASts>
<Doc:Issr>ZYLCUS30</Doc:Issr>
<Doc:Crspdt>BSDTGB20</Doc:Crspdt>
<Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
<Doc:IssdDtTm>2014-09-12T13:16:19Z</Doc:IssdDtTm>
</Sw:RMARecrd>

<Sw:RMARecrd>
<Sw:Tp>Received</Sw:Tp>
<Sw:RMASts>Enabled</Sw:RMASts>
<Doc:Issr>AGIGUS30</Doc:Issr>
<Doc:Crspdt>BSDTUS30</Doc:Crspdt>
<Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
<Doc:IssdDtTm>2013-06-26T13:20:20Z</Doc:IssdDtTm>
</Sw:RMARecrd>

<Sw:RMARecrd>
<Sw:Tp>Received</Sw:Tp>
<Sw:RMASts>Enabled</Sw:RMASts>
<Doc:Issr>AQRMUS30</Doc:Issr>
<Doc:Crspdt>BSDTUS30</Doc:Crspdt>
<Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
<Doc:IssdDtTm>2014-11-05T02:17:34Z</Doc:IssdDtTm>
</Sw:RMARecrd>

<Sw:RMARecrd>
<Sw:Tp>Received</Sw:Tp>
<Sw:RMASts>Enabled</Sw:RMASts>
<Doc:Issr>BLBGGB20</Doc:Issr>
<Doc:Crspdt>BSDTUS30</Doc:Crspdt>
<Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
<Doc:IssdDtTm>2015-11-20T10:30:18Z</Doc:IssdDtTm>
<SwSec:Signature>
<SwSec:SignedInfo><Sw:Reference><Sw:DigestValue>s6ytg+2eV+e4Pg0UzUwD+lW0hAudR3N/VeSwleg3bzU=</Sw:DigestValue></Sw:Reference></SwSec:SignedInfo>
<SwSec:SignatureValue>
PEMF@Proc-Type: 4,MIC-ONLY
Content-Domain: RFC822
EntrustFile-Version: 2.0
Originator-DN: cn=blbggb2l-2,ou=prod,o=blbggb2l,o=swift
Orig-SN: 1416707530
MIC-Info: SHA256, RSA,
 TwfVoV22y+iqiNwiZ5p40kGk7a9Gm8bHcdPH1bzF19063Q8BsglE59dF8Fsscnk8
 M1SuDzwAVZFI4Na1iqf/cAbuugVbXKThBUAtNrqypVehrsl4BOXkU3LK0XGVtrDj
 oVHsBs0k8zhk/6cOBUIWr2O+WQA9opvgMEYdaNqVW2OC+UCBsDV8gDyZFvi/cnVR
 mEn4OOEKfNrQMvPR+ackPWFdb5FE70N/L2IZjrYGPcVbkR/UBg6zCOojuEOqbSdO
 EEzT5DVd8d3AHb2NeqXoYNnRmkxK9qqIijCw5VHTPCBANmKuJVlciMW0Vv+rrbsU
 MIIP/MkoPPW17r0Ts9acoQ==
</SwSec:SignatureValue>
<SwSec:KeyInfo>
<SwSec:SignDN>cn=blbggb2l-2,ou=prod,o=blbggb2l,o=swift</SwSec:SignDN>
<SwSec:CertPolicyId>1.3.21.6.2</SwSec:CertPolicyId>
</SwSec:KeyInfo>
<SwSec:Manifest>
<Sw:Reference><Sw:DigestRef>Authorisation</Sw:DigestRef><Sw:DigestValue>aLxFLajsQFYloHlaU2GZPfudNO9sdeqGPb3G8GBkweA=</Sw:DigestValue></Sw:Reference>
<Sw:Reference><Sw:DigestRef>Sw.E2S</Sw:DigestRef><Sw:DigestValue>7XFoTufTG0l2fMNoC+mzpAmTKgeipVlcTK0Q3KlW8fw=</Sw:DigestValue></Sw:Reference>
<Sw:Reference><Sw:DigestRef>Sw.NRS</Sw:DigestRef><Sw:DigestValue>qRuWmiLLsuT2lamWkG8Zo7qRrxqolRCWNLPs//OsvCE=</Sw:DigestValue></Sw:Reference>
</SwSec:Manifest>
</SwSec:Signature>
</Sw:RMARecrd>

<Sw:RMARecrd>
<Sw:Tp>Received</Sw:Tp>
<Sw:RMASts>Enabled</Sw:RMASts>
<Doc:Issr>BLBGGB50</Doc:Issr>
<Doc:Crspdt>BSDTUS30</Doc:Crspdt>
<Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
<Doc:IssdDtTm>2014-11-17T17:30:27Z</Doc:IssdDtTm>
</Sw:RMARecrd>

<Sw:RMARecrd>
<Sw:Tp>Received</Sw:Tp>
<Sw:RMASts>Enabled</Sw:RMASts>
<Doc:Issr>BRIPUS40</Doc:Issr>
<Doc:Crspdt>BSDTUS30</Doc:Crspdt>
<Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
<Doc:IssdDtTm>2014-07-22T06:28:12Z</Doc:IssdDtTm>
</Sw:RMARecrd>

<Sw:RMARecrd>
<Sw:Tp>Received</Sw:Tp>
<Sw:RMASts>Enabled</Sw:RMASts>
<Doc:Issr>CFSMAU20</Doc:Issr>
<Doc:Crspdt>BSDTUS30</Doc:Crspdt>
<Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
<Doc:IssdDtTm>2015-02-26T23:24:52Z</Doc:IssdDtTm>
</Sw:RMARecrd>

<Sw:RMARecrd>
<Sw:Tp>Received</Sw:Tp>
<Sw:RMASts>Enabled</Sw:RMASts>
<Doc:Issr>CITIBGS0</Doc:Issr>
<Doc:Crspdt>BSDTUS30</Doc:Crspdt>
<Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
<Doc:IssdDtTm>2014-04-08T07:34:10Z</Doc:IssdDtTm>
</Sw:RMARecrd>

<Sw:RMARecrd>
<Sw:Tp>Received</Sw:Tp>
<Sw:RMASts>Enabled</Sw:RMASts>
<Doc:Issr>CITICZP0</Doc:Issr>
<Doc:Crspdt>BSDTUS30</Doc:Crspdt>
<Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
<Doc:IssdDtTm>2014-01-20T07:52:11Z</Doc:IssdDtTm>
</Sw:RMARecrd>

</Sw:RMAFile>
```

Given the above file, the output I am hoping to achieve is the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Sw:RMAFile xmlns:Sw="urn:swift:snl:ns.Sw" xmlns:Doc="urn:swift:snl:ns.Doc" xmlns:SwSec="urn:swift:snl:ns.SwSec">

<Sw:RMAFileHdr>
<Sw:Bic8Lst>
<Doc:Bic8>BSDTGB20</Doc:Bic8>
</Sw:Bic8Lst>

<Sw:SvcLst>
<Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
</Sw:SvcLst>

<Sw:FileMaintncSts>Partial</Sw:FileMaintncSts>
<Sw:FileDesc/><Sw:CrDtTm>2016-08-01T10:17:02Z</Sw:CrDtTm>
<Sw:TltRecrd>254</Sw:TltRecrd>
<Sw:LAU><Sw:LAUVal>RRgL2lsocXDswCHxgnf4ww==</Sw:LAUVal></Sw:LAU>

</Sw:RMAFileHdr>

<Sw:RMARecrd>
<Sw:Tp>Received</Sw:Tp>
<Sw:RMASts>Rejected</Sw:RMASts>
<Doc:Issr>ZYLCUS30</Doc:Issr>
<Doc:Crspdt>BSDTGB20</Doc:Crspdt>
<Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
<Doc:IssdDtTm>2014-09-12T13:16:19Z</Doc:IssdDtTm>
</Sw:RMARecrd>

</Sw:RMAFile>
```

Comment: Please format your post.

Comment: Why the close votes?

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming the missing `<` is fixed near the beginning of the XML...)

You don't actually want to *extract* (select) the data, you want to *delete* the data you don't want to see.

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ xml ed -t -d '//Sw:RMARecrd[Doc:Crspdt != "BSDTGB20" and Doc:Crspdt != "MITMUS30"]' -nl data.xml
```

This returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sw:RMAFile xmlns:Sw="urn:swift:snl:ns.Sw" xmlns:Doc="urn:swift:snl:ns.Doc" xmlns:SwSec="urn:swift:snl:ns.SwSec">
  <Sw:RMAFileHdr>
    <Sw:Bic8Lst>
      <Doc:Bic8>BSDTGB20</Doc:Bic8>
      <Doc:Bic8>BSDTUS30</Doc:Bic8>
      <Doc:Bic8>BWTRUS30</Doc:Bic8>
      <Doc:Bic8>MELNJPJ0</Doc:Bic8>
      <Doc:Bic8>NEIMGB20</Doc:Bic8>
      <Doc:Bic8>ZYHJGB20</Doc:Bic8>
      <Doc:Bic8>ZYIYUS30</Doc:Bic8>
      <Doc:Bic8>ZYJDGB20</Doc:Bic8>
    </Sw:Bic8Lst>
    <Sw:SvcLst>
      <Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
    </Sw:SvcLst>
    <Sw:FileMaintncSts>Partial</Sw:FileMaintncSts>
    <Sw:FileDesc/>
    <Sw:CrDtTm>2016-08-01T10:17:02Z</Sw:CrDtTm>
    <Sw:TltRecrd>254</Sw:TltRecrd>
    <Sw:LAU>
      <Sw:LAUVal>RRgL2lsocXDswCHxgnf4ww==</Sw:LAUVal>
    </Sw:LAU>
  </Sw:RMAFileHdr>
  <Sw:RMARecrd>
    <Sw:Tp>Received</Sw:Tp>
    <Sw:RMASts>Rejected</Sw:RMASts>
    <Doc:Issr>ZYLCUS30</Doc:Issr>
    <Doc:Crspdt>BSDTGB20</Doc:Crspdt>
    <Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
    <Doc:IssdDtTm>2014-09-12T13:16:19Z</Doc:IssdDtTm>
  </Sw:RMARecrd>
</Sw:RMAFile>
```

If you additionally want to remove the corresponding `<Doc:Bic8>` entries:

```
$ xml ed -t \
    -d '//Sw:RMARecrd[Doc:Crspdt != "BSDTGB20" and Doc:Crspdt != "MITMUS30"]' \
    -d '//Doc:Bic8[. != "BSDTGB20" and . != "MITMUS30"]' -nl data.xml
```

Which returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sw:RMAFile xmlns:Sw="urn:swift:snl:ns.Sw" xmlns:Doc="urn:swift:snl:ns.Doc" xmlns:SwSec="urn:swift:snl:ns.SwSec">
  <Sw:RMAFileHdr>
    <Sw:Bic8Lst>
      <Doc:Bic8>BSDTGB20</Doc:Bic8>
    </Sw:Bic8Lst>
    <Sw:SvcLst>
      <Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
    </Sw:SvcLst>
    <Sw:FileMaintncSts>Partial</Sw:FileMaintncSts>
    <Sw:FileDesc/>
    <Sw:CrDtTm>2016-08-01T10:17:02Z</Sw:CrDtTm>
    <Sw:TltRecrd>254</Sw:TltRecrd>
    <Sw:LAU>
      <Sw:LAUVal>RRgL2lsocXDswCHxgnf4ww==</Sw:LAUVal>
    </Sw:LAU>
  </Sw:RMAFileHdr>
  <Sw:RMARecrd>
    <Sw:Tp>Received</Sw:Tp>
    <Sw:RMASts>Rejected</Sw:RMASts>
    <Doc:Issr>ZYLCUS30</Doc:Issr>
    <Doc:Crspdt>BSDTGB20</Doc:Crspdt>
    <Doc:SvcNm>swift.fin!p</Doc:SvcNm>
    <Doc:IssdDtTm>2014-09-12T13:16:19Z</Doc:IssdDtTm>
  </Sw:RMARecrd>
</Sw:RMAFile>
```

You may possibly want to be more restrictive with the matching than that though and specify the path down to the nodes without resorting to `//`.

Comment: i want the same output but using ksh script.

Comment: @Trupti Install XMLStarlet, then call it from you `ksh` script as above. You do _not_ want to use line-oriented tools for doing XML processing. In general, [don't parse structured data with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Can we do it directly using scripting commands?

Comment: @Trupti You could update (edit) your question to include this as a prerequisite if you wish, and someone else may answer. I personally think this is the easiest, most robust, and the most portable solution. I will not give you a `sed`, `awk` or `grep` one-liner to solve it in another way. Sorry.

Comment: `xmlstarlet` **IS** a scripting command, in exactly the same way that `grep`, or `awk`, or `sed` are scripting commands.  It just happens to be one that's written specifically to handle XML data, which is a good thing because parsing XML or HTML [with regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) just [doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/137158)

Comment: @Trupti Please see Cas' comment and associated links.

Comment: @cas yes, it is scripting command, but for that i need to install XMLStarlet.
As it is corporate systerm there are limitations to download/install it.
Can you pls suggest a way!

Comment: @Trupti In a situation like this, I would speak to a manager and ask them if they would be happy to have (and take responsibility for) a solution that was using tools to perform a task (parse & edit XML) these tools were not designed to perform, or if it would be better to install a tool specifically developed for performing just exactly this task.

Comment: @Trupti do you have python or perl?  if so, you can easily install an XML parsing module (e.g. under your home directory, like in `~/bin/`).  With perl, it's trivially easy - just use the `cpan` command....and not much harder with python.